# Find files inside subfolders bash

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write a script which takes in a folder and deletes all files within subfolders in that folder.

eg:

- abc

  - a.txt
  - b.txt
- efg

  - e.txt
- x.txt

The script when run, should delete a.txt, b.txt and e.txt and not x.txt(since it is not inside a folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you want to decide when you write a bash script is to decide which command you want to use.

The `find` command returns all files in a folder, recursively.

`find ${dir} -name "*.txt" -delete`

The above command searches the dir(directory stored in a variable) for file names ending with `.txt` and deletes them.
But what if you want to find files within sub directories only?

You could use:
`find ${dir}/*/ -name "*.txt" -delete`

Notice how we added `/*/` to denote that find for all folders inside this folder.
You could additionally add the check `-type f` to affirm that we are deleting a file and not anything else.

Comment: `find "$dir"` or `find "${dir}"` -- the curly braces make no difference to correctness, but the quotes stop your directory from being word-split; test with a directory name with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

With **`find`** command:

Sample `test` folder structure:

```
$ tree test
test
├── abc
│   ├── a.txt
│   └── b.txt
├── efg
│   └── e.txt
└── x.txt
```

---

The crucial command:

```
find test -mindepth 2 -type f -delete
```

---

Viewing results:

```
$ tree test
test
├── abc
├── efg
└── x.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

this one here

```
find */ -name *.txt -type f | xargs rm -f
```